# Let $X_1,...,X_{25}$ be a random sample from $U(1,\theta)$. Find the $UMPT(\alpha = 0.05)$ for $H_0: 1<\theta<3 \text{ vs. } H_1: \theta>3.$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,...,X_{25}$ be a random sample from $U(1, \theta)$, and $ \theta > 1$. Find the $UMPT(\alpha = 0.05)$ for $H_0: 1<\theta<3 \text{ vs. } H_1: \theta>3.$

I'm trying to use the Generalized LRT theorem but I'm not sure how to find the MLE of $\theta$ for the compound distribution. I know that for a sample of $25$ uniform distributions with parameters $(0,\theta)$ the MLE of $\theta$ is $X_{(25)}$.

It's okay in this case to transform the random variable?

Any suggestions would be great!